# How to see if a certain class exists in a list

Tags: python, list, types, comparison, comparison-operators

I have a class, `user`, that has an attribute `metadata`.

`metadata` is a list of objects, each with different classes, for example:

`user.metatada = [Employee(), Student(), OtherClass()]`

In an update script, I need to check, if a certain type exists in a list, like so:

```
if type(Employee()) in user.metadata:
  replace user.metadata[indexOfThatEmployee] with new Employee()
else:
  user.metadata.append(new Employee())
```

is there anyway to easily to check if a certain type exists in a list?

Comment: You need to check whether that `class` is there in that attribute and replace if it exists ?

Comment: basically, yes.

Answer (score 0):

Got it.

```
test = [Employee()]

if any(isinstance(x, Employee) for x in user.metadata):
    user.metadata = [x for x in user.metadata if not isinstance(x, Employee)] + test
else:
    user.metadata = user.metadata + test
```

So this will check if there exists an object in the list that is an instance of the Employee class, if so, filter the list of the existing Employee object and add in the new one, if it doesn't exist, just add it in.